Out of love for something/someone
Is the phrase above a natural choice in these two sentences below.
(Let's say on a bag of flour, you can read the the following)
We made it (the flour) out of love for baking.
They gave her a present out of love for her.

More generally, you can use the construction out of XXXX for YYYY where XXXX (love, respect, concern, pity, regard, gratitude,...) is some attitude / emotional response towards the "target" person or thing YYYY (baking, her,...).

Yes, out of love for is a valid phrase as shown in the many hits in Google Books.  An example is in Out of Love for My Kin: Aristocratic Family Life in the Lands ... - Page107.

We made it (the flour) out of love for baking.


They gave her a present out of love for her.

These two examples are fine.  The second one is a common usage.
The first one has a similar usage here.

While both are reasonable, it is perhaps a bad choice for the verb "made," because "make X out of Y" is a common construction meaning "construct X using Y," as in "I made this cake out of flour, sugar, and eggs." It further complicates things that it's a bit of a common joke or playful mixed metaphor to include list "love" as an ingredient especially in baking: "I made this cake for you with a cup of flour, 2 eggs, and a whole lotta love." (But note, there's a difference between "did X out of love"—love was the reason—and "did X with love"—I felt love while doing it.)
Other contexts might have less danger of confusion. "I built this shed out of fear that the rain would damage my lawn mower." Nobody jokes about using fear as a building material, and there is little danger of a garden-path sentence.

"Out of love" phrase meaning :".
If anything is done out of love, the giver asks nothing in return. They simply observed another person in need and chose to help. Helping someone who is struggling and asking nothing in return is perhaps the purest form of doing something out of love.
Now looking at both examples given by OP:

Example 1:
Is the phrase above a natural choice in these two sentences below.
(Let's say on a bag of flour, you can read the the following) We made it (the flour) out of love for baking.

In this example, the company means to say that cooking is their passion and they had put their heart and soul into the product.

Example 2:
They gave her a present out of love for her.

Please note that you cannot use this phrase in all situations. If it is your daughter's birthday and you are buying a dress for her you cannot say it. But if you are buying a cottage for your grown up daughter you can use the phrase.The above phrase should generally be used if you are donating something.
They distributed cake and candies on New Year's Eve, in the orphanage out of love for the children.
